# Canvas saving & restoring

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm currently doing an app which allow the user to make some slideshow. I'm using fabricjs to make them add text & stuff on the current slide. But i want them to be able to add new slide aswell.

So i need a way to save and store the current slide (canvas) when they hit a "new slide" button.
Other thing is that the user is allowed to edit previous canvas by selecting them from a columns.

I'm relatively new to html5 & fabricjs so i have really no idea how to do that. I've tried using the clone function but didnt really work out, so does the drawImage from the previous canvas.

Any thoughts that can help me to get started on this ?

I've also been thinking about the way to store the canvas created, and i was wondering if arraylists were a good way to go.

Thanks for your help

tl;dr : I want to save a canvas, clear it and be able restore it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use canvas serialization to save the canvas to JSON and restore the canvas later when you want. For a detailed tutorial [this fabricjs article](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#serialization) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.fillStyle= 'red'
//  draw a rectangle with default settings
     ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,150);
     //  Save the default state
     ctx.save();   



 ctx.fillStyle = '#66FFFF'       
     ctx.fillRect( 15,15,120,120); 
     // Save the current state
    // ctx.save();


 // Restore previous state
     ctx.restore();
     ctx.fillRect(45,45,60,60);
```

example from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/canvas_states.htm